# Cannot get MySQL 5.7 to install on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, dpkg

After running updates and installs on my Ubuntu 16.04 Digital Ocean Droplet (with their LAMP stack installed), I can't can't get MySQL to install... I've tried numerous posts on here but none of them seem to work and the result is always the same for me:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /etc/mysql/my.cnf is already managed by my.cnf.bak
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I suspect it's the 'update-alternatives' line that is causing the issue, but I have no my.cnf.bak on the system. I'm not a server guy, so any help would be amazing!

Results when attempting to install via Aptitude:

```
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /etc/mysql/my.cnf is already managed by my.cnf.bak
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /etc/mysql/my.cnf is already managed by my.cnf.bak
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

Comment: did you run `apt-get update` first?

Comment: That's actually what broke everything. I ran apt-get update and the updates have caused this break

Comment: do you have aptitude installed? what resolution does `aptitude install mysql-server` give you? https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/aptitude.html.en

Comment: I just installed Aptitude and I get the same errors when I go that route... I'll attach that to the post

Comment: this is why no one configures servers manually anymore lol aptitude is telling you mysql-server it at the most recent version (5.7) but can't configure it due to an old config file. see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/643251/having-trouble-installing-and-removing-mysql-in-ubuntu

Comment: Do you have any idea where I would find and remove this old file? I can't find it for the life of me

Comment: Yes you can try and remove the file, but i'd first try a clean install. see the link above!

Comment: Same issues following all the steps... :(

Comment: can you run `apt-get purge mysql-server` and then try `cd /etc/mysql/` please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176435/discussion-between-edward-and-brunam).

Comment: So ? Anyone has solution ?